# Timeseries of tweets using Python3, Pandas, and Numpy: AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Tags: python, numpy, twitter

I am using a code (by Marco Bonzanini) to plot the frequency of tweets over a period of time. My tweets are contained in a JSONL file. Unfortunately when running the code in the terminal I get the above cited error. How can I manipulate the code so that Numpy can correctly transform the datetime?

(I use Python 3.6, also I did see that a similar question was asked but I am not sure how to incorporate the answer into the code as it is quite different).

```
import sys 
import json 
from datetime import datetime 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import pickle 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  fname = sys.argv[1] 

  with open(fname, 'r') as f: 
    all_dates = [] 
    for line in f: 
      tweet = json.loads(line) 
      all_dates.append(tweet.get('created_at')) 
    idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(all_dates) 
    ones = np.ones(len(all_dates)) 
    # the actual series (at series of 1s for the moment) 
    my_series = pd.Series(ones, index=idx) 

    # Resampling / bucketing into 1-minute buckets 
    per_minute = my_series.resample('1Min', how='sum').fillna(0) 

    # Plotting the series 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
    ax.grid(True) 
    ax.set_title("Tweet Frequencies") 

    hours = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=20) 
    date_formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M') 

    datemin = datetime(2011, 10, 31, 15, 0) 
    datemax = datetime(2017, 10, 31, 18, 0) 

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours) 
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter) 
    ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax) 
    max_freq = per_minute.max() 
    ax.set_ylim(0, max_freq) 
    ax.plot(per_minute.index, per_minute) 

    plt.savefig('tweet_time_series.png')
```

The Json Lines Data looks like this (two tweets, second line starting at: {"created_at": "Fri Oct 24 ...)

{"created_at": "Fri Oct 24 20:21:15 +0000 2014", "id": 525743844839522305, "id_str": "525743844839522305", "text": "\u0628\u0644 \u0623\u0645\u0644\u0627\u064b \u0648\u0634\u0645\u0633\u0627 \u0648\u0642\u0645\u062d\u0627  \n\u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0646\u0643 \u0633\u064a\u062f\u064a \u0628\u0633\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0648\u062d \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0646\n\u0648\u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u0646\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0637\u0646 \n\u0641\u0645 \u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f \u064a\u0643\u0641\u064a \u0644\u0643\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u063a\u0627\u062a\n\u0637\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627 \u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u062a \u062d\u0627\u0644\u0629 \u0645\u0646 \u062d\u0627\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629", "truncated": false, "entities": {"hashtags": [], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": []}, "source": "http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone", "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "user": {"id": 1948848392, "id_str": "1948848392", "name": "Ali Bazzi", "screen_name": "DeputyAliBazzi", "location": "", "description": "\u0645\u0627 \u0632\u0627\u0644 \u0647\u0646\u0627\u0643 \u0623\u0645\u0644... \u064a\u0633\u062a\u0648\u0637\u0646 \u062a\u062c\u0627\u0639\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0646\u064a\u0646.", "url": null, "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}}, "protected": false, "followers_count": 34918, "friends_count": 362, "listed_count": 13, "created_at": "Wed Oct 09 07:55:26 +0000 2013", "favourites_count": 6016, "utc_offset": null, "time_zone": null, "geo_enabled": true, "verified": false, "statuses_count": 5188, "lang": "en", "contributors_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "is_translation_enabled": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883631999499612161/6Y9QbL52_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883631999499612161/6Y9QbL52_normal.jpg", "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1948848392/1415834468", "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "has_extended_profile": false, "default_profile": true, "default_profile_image": false, "following": false, "follow_request_sent": false, "notifications": false, "translator_type": "none"}, "geo": null, "coordinates": null, "place": null, "contributors": null, "is_quote_status": false, "retweet_count": 14, "favorite_count": 21, "favorited": false, "retweeted": false, "lang": "ar"}
{"created_at": "Fri Oct 24 20:18:39 +0000 2014", "id": 525743192868519936, "id_str": "525743192868519936", "text": "\u0645\u0646\u0630 \u0643\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0627\u0621 \u0648\u0646\u062d\u0646 \u0646\u0639\u0634\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0631 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0646\u0628\u064a\u0627\u0621 \n\u062f\u0645\u0646\u0627 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u062f\u064a\u0627\u0646 \n\u0648\u0623\u0634\u0644\u0627\u0624\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u0644\u0642\u0629 \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u062c\u0639 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0645\u0627\u0621\n\u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0646\u0643 \u0633\u064a\u062f\u064a \u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u062a \u0644\u0627 \u064a\u0635\u0646\u0639 \u062c\u0631\u062d\u0627\n(\u062a\u0627\u0628\u0639)", "truncated": false, "entities": {"hashtags": [], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": []}, "source": "http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone", "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "user": {"id": 1948848392, "id_str": "1948848392", "name": "Ali Bazzi", "screen_name": "DeputyAliBazzi", "location": "", "description": "\u0645\u0627 \u0632\u0627\u0644 \u0647\u0646\u0627\u0643 \u0623\u0645\u0644... \u064a\u0633\u062a\u0648\u0637\u0646 \u062a\u062c\u0627\u0639\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0646\u064a\u0646.", "url": null, "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}}, "protected": false, "followers_count": 34918, "friends_count": 362, "listed_count": 13, "created_at": "Wed Oct 09 07:55:26 +0000 2013", "favourites_count": 6016, "utc_offset": null, "time_zone": null, "geo_enabled": true, "verified": false, "statuses_count": 5188, "lang": "en", "contributors_enabled": false, "is_translator": false, "is_translation_enabled": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883631999499612161/6Y9QbL52_normal.jpg", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/883631999499612161/6Y9QbL52_normal.jpg", "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1948848392/1415834468", "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_use_background_image": true, "has_extended_profile": false, "default_profile": true, "default_profile_image": false, "following": false, "follow_request_sent": false, "notifications": false, "translator_type": "none"}, "geo": null, "coordinates": null, "place": null, "contributors": null, "is_quote_status": false, "retweet_count": 13, "favorite_count": 19, "favorited": false, "retweeted": false, "lang": "ar"}

Comment: I haven't tested but I think the error comes from the resampling: you have to use `T` or `min` instead of `Min` to resample for each minute

Comment: @FlorianGD Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried it with 1min, 1T but both resulted in the same Error Message!

Comment: Could you provide a part of your data, because we cannot reproduce your code, which makes it hard to help you. If the json loading part works, maybe just `all_dates`

Comment: I extracted two tweets to show how the data is structured. Does this help?